# Did Shouko kill people to make the Setsugetsuka dolls?

Tags: unbreakable-machine-doll

It's hinted that in order to make a banned doll, you have to use human parts. In the manga, Charlotte is struck with how much bio parts Yaya has.

Did Shouko actually kill people to make the Setsugetsuka dolls?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, she did (Yaya is a banned doll, as Charlotte discovers `Manga, anime`). Banned Dolls are created using living parts or a whole living organism, human or otherwise (like Frey's dogs). The best banned dolls use human parts, and the machine dolls (Yaya supposedly is one) are made from living humans altogether.

`Anime episode 12, talk between Magnus and the teacher.`

Shouko is shown in a flashback bargaining for Raishin's body (part of the reason she left Yaya with him to begin with) so she could make more automata `also episode 12`.

So all Magnus' dolls, Elf Speeder's butler `ep12`, Setsugestuka, and probably cannibal candy`she could use magic independently inside the vault.` were once living people (or parts of) turned into automata.

Let's not even go into the ethics discussion... XD

Comment: I didn't follow the novel, and I stopped reading manga for some time so I don't remember reading about this. Do you have any reference for what you are saying here?

Comment: From the Anime and some manga parts.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is almost a decade old, but I'm going to give you the correct answer. The answers given by Mindwin Remember Monica are completely wrong.

It's true that Shouko used human bodies to create Banned Doll, but that's only true for creating Oborofuji. Shouko didn't use human bodies to make the Setsugetsuka. If you remember the scene in episode 3, she said: “That thing was a failure. It wasn’t beautiful at all.”. Shouko didn't like the Oborofuji. It was because of the way it was created. The Oborofuji was made from the body of death row inmates. She was forced to create it by Sakaki and the Japanese army. It went against her feelings. I'm sure that Shouko didn't kill the inmates on death row, but Sakaki did the killing blow. You don't have to kill a person to create a Banned Doll, it can be created by using a living object, as in the case of the Garm. The same goes for the Maschinensoldat such as Shin. The part where Charlotte saw Yaya's body was more human-like than Sigmund's was because it was made out of Shouko's Sell.

Let me clear something up about what Mindwin Remember Monica answered.

> Shouko is shown in a flashback bargaining for Raishin's body (part of
> the reason she left Yaya with him to begin with) so she could make
> more automata also episode 12.

She didn't choose Yaya for Raishin in order to create more automatons. She wants to create a Machine Doll, and Raishin is one of the keys to creating it, using the Kuretsuba's Blood to make it happen.

> So all Magnus' dolls, Elf Speeder's butler ep12, Setsugestuka, and
> probably cannibal candyshe could use magic independently inside the
> vault. were once living people (or parts of) turned into automata.

Magnus' Squadron is made up of Nadeshiko's organs. Shin is a Maschinensoldat made from a real, living human being. The Setsugetsuka is made from Shouko's Sell. There is no information as to how Eliza was created, except that she was created during the Renaissance period.